# Optimisation Problem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

Given a vector $\vec{c}$ and a radius $r$, solve the problem:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{maximise}}
& & \vec{c} \cdotp \vec{x}=a \\
& \text{subject to}
& & ||x^2||=r^2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be the angle between $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{c}$. Then assuming the constraint is $\|\vec{x}\|^2 = r^2$, we have

$$
  \vec{c} \cdot \vec{x}
  = \|\vec{c}\| \|\vec{x}\| \cos\theta
  = \|\vec{c}\| |r| \cos\theta
$$

which is maximised when $\theta = 0$.

The geometric interpretation is that for $\vec{x}$ of fixed length $|r|$, the dot product $\vec{c} \cdot \vec{x}$ is maximised by taking $\vec{x}$ pointing in the same direction as $\vec{c}$,

$$ \vec{x} = |r| \frac{\vec{c}}{\|\vec{c}\|} .$$

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, I was wondering how to approach this if $\vec{c}$ and $\vec{x}$ were $n$x$1$ vectors. Sorry this wasn't clear in the question. Am I correct in assuming the dot product relationship only holds for 3-D space?

Comment: @jp412 $\vec{c} \cdot \vec{x} = \|\vec{c}\| \|\vec{x}\| \cos\theta$ works in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for all positive integer $n$, with $\theta$ the angle between the vectors.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help